# Form data not Posting for later PHP processing

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Hello I am a first time poster.  I tried searching for an answer, but nothing really obvious popped out at me from the material already posted.  I need another pair of eyes on this, as I cannot figure out why my form data isn't posting.

I am making a shopping cart using session variables to store data short term.  Ultimately, during checkout, this order data will be finalized to a database.  When I render my shopping cart contents for review, I need to provide my customers the freedom to update quantity (or delete).  Keeping this as uncluttered as possible, here is the html rendering of the cart contents (without headings, totals, etc):

```
<form action="mas_cart.php" method="post">
    <table id="shCart" border="1" width="800px" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">DSC0679</td>
            <td align="left">7.2H x 11W Glossy Paper </td>
            <td align="center">No</td><td align="center">$55</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="inp_qty" type="text" name="DSC0679_unsigned_7.2H x 11W Glossy Paper $55" value="1" size="3">
            </td>
            <td align="right">55.00</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">MRS5293</td>
            <td align="left">7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper </td>
            <td align="center">Yes</td>
            <td align="center">$55</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="inp_qty" type="text" name="MRS5293_signed_7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper $55" value="1" size="3">
            </td>
            <td align="right">55.00</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="left">MRS5293</td>
            <td align="left">7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper </td>
            <td align="center">No</td>
            <td align="center">$55</td>
            <td align="center">
                <input id="inp_qty" type="text" name="MRS5293_unsigned_7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper $55" value="2" size="3">
            </td>
            <td align="right">110.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="true"/>
    <input type="image" src="images/save-changes.png" style="border:1px solid rgb(50,50,50)" alt="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

And here is the PHP code which is supposed to process updates:

```
//update section
if(isset($_POST['save'])) {
   foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item => $qty) {
     if($_POST[$item]==0 || $_POST[$item]=="") {
         unset($_SESSION['cart'][$item]); } 
     else {
         $_SESSION['cart'][$item] = $_POST[$item];} }
```

In execution, `$_POST['save']` is properly set, but `$_POST[$item]` returns undefined index:

> Notice: Undefined index: DSC0679_unsigned_7.2H x 11W Glossy Paper $55 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\mas_cart.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined index: MRS5293_signed_7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper $55 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\mas_cart.php on line 57
>
> Notice: Undefined index: MRS5293_unsigned_7.3H x 11W Glossy Paper $55 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aaa\mas_cart.php on line 57

Basically, the conditional in post processing always renders as true, since the index is undefined, so updating spits out errors and clears the cart.  I know it is hateful asking someone else to look at my code, but I am having the very worst time figuring this out.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Help?

Comment: Use print_r($_POST); to check what is actually being submitted by the script

Comment: Your input names are invalid plus they're not defined. There are spaces, dots, dollar signs etc. That won't wash at all. Therefore `Notice: Undefined index` ;-)

Comment: Plus, having an `x` with spaces to the left and right of it in your input names, PHP's trying to do math, but it doesn't know how to count properly. *cough*

Comment: @sanki `$items` is defined in `as $item` in `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item => $qty) {`

Comment: My guess is on your posted code. You've pasted this from source on the Web. I know this because **2 times $55 = $110** (*I'm so smart*) <= `value="2"` and `<td align="center">$55</td>` what is that doing in your question? Start by changing one of your inputs to `DSC0679_unsigned_7-2H_x_11W_Glossy_Paper_55` and you'll start getting results and do the same for the other inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I propose you change the structure of your HTML:

```
<form action="mas_cart.php" method="post">
    <table id="shCart" border="1" width="800px" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <input readonly type="text" name="id[]" value="DSC0679"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <input readonly type="text" name="desc[]" value="7.2H x 11W Glossy Paper"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input readonly type="text" name="something[]" value="No"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input readonly type="text" id="price0" name="price[]" value="55.00"/>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input type="number" id="quantity0" name="quantity[]" min="0" size="3"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <input readonly type="text" id="text0" name="ext[]"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        ...

    <input type="hidden" id="count" name="count" value="3"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="save" value="true"/>
    <input type="image" src="images/save-changes.png" style="border:1px solid rgb(50,50,50)" alt="Save Changes"/>
</form>
```

If you end a `name` with `[]` it treats that value as an array rather than just a single value. Also I gave you the IDs for the price, quantity and ext fields as well as a product count so you can do on-the-fly calculations in Javascript if you want to. What you can then do in your PHP (I haven't tested it):

```
$products = array();

if(isset($_POST['save']) && is_array($_POST['id'])) {
    for($i=0,$l=count($_POST['id']);$i<$l;$i++) {
        $products[$i] = array();

        $fields = array('id','desc','something','price','quantity','ext');

        foreach($fields as $field)
            { $products[$i][$field] = $_POST[$field][$i]; }
    }
}
```

Then for instance you can get the first product quantity as: `$products[0]['quantity']`

In a real-world application using something like this you would only need the ID and quantity of each product. Calculations would be done on the back-end (never trust the user) and product information wouldn't really be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I was just logging on to post an update, and found that some of the posted responses point this direction as well.  It turned out that HTML/PHP puts restrictions on allowed characters for form 'name's.  Both spaces and the '.' don't work and get substituted out for "_".  Interestingly, '$' continues to work just fine... go figure.  When I reformatted my 'item' string a few minutes ago, the problem went away, and I did my happy dance.  Thanks to everyone who took the time to look into my problem :)!!!